# Identifying positive and negative words in text

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to work out how to scan a text file of a conversation find how many positive words and negative words there are. The positive and negative words are contained within two separate text files which are used to 'scan' the conversation text file.

After it finds the number of positive and negative words I am trying to get it to tally each up and then tell me if there are more positive or negative words found.

I have the code below so far, it only gives me a count on the positive words. I am not looking at something like NLP at this stage just something on a much more basic level.

I think I have the second part looking for the negative words in the wrong location. And I think I need to use a boolean to tell me if there are more positive or negative words found, but I can't work out how to do it.

I am pretty stuck as I am new to Java, and programing in general.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package omgilisearch;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SentimentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          printAllCounts(
            readWordFile("ConversationTest.txt", loadKeywords("PositiveWords.txt")));
        }
    public static void main1(String[] args) throws Exception {
          printAllCounts(
            readWordFile("ConversationTest.txt", loadKeywords("NegativeWords.txt")));
        }

        private static Map<String, Integer> readWordFile(
          String fname, Set<String> keywords) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
          final Map<String, Integer> frequencyData = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
          for (Scanner wordFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fname)); 
            wordFile.hasNext();) 
          {
            final String word = wordFile.next();
            if (keywords.contains(word)) 
              frequencyData.put(word, getCount(word, frequencyData) + 1);
          }
          return frequencyData;
        }


        private static void printAllCounts(Map<String, Integer> frequencyData) {
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
          System.out.println(" Occurrences Word");
          for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : frequencyData.entrySet())
            System.out.printf("%15d %s\n", e.getValue(), e.getKey());
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        }

        private static int getCount(String word, Map<String, Integer> frequencyData) {
            return frequencyData.containsKey(word)? frequencyData.get(word) : 0;
        }

        private static Set<String> loadKeywords(String fname) 
        throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
          final Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
          for (Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(fname)); s.hasNext();) 
            result.add(s.next());
          return result;
        }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
(You would need to hard-code the +/-ve words and the test text).

Comment: BTW - is 'not negative' 2 -ve words, or 1 +ve phrase?

Comment: Sorry Andrew, not following what you are asking in your second comment?

Comment: 'not negative' is a 'double negative' or a 'positive'. :)

Comment: Hahaha...Got you now Andrew! : ) @home, as I said I am new. Are you saying I should delete the main1 and have both fall under the main?

Comment: @Eagle: I don't know, your code just contains a method that's never called, so I wonder what it's good for...

Answer (score 1):

You would have to have some array of so called "bad" words (wich are hard coded) and then iterate through the whole text file and compare every word in the array with the word you currently inspecting. If the word matches with one of the words in the array, then increase some variable that is holding the amount of badwords eg. badWords++;. I believe this approach should work.

Comment: Could't I basically get a "Total" count for each (i.e. Positive and Negative words) and then find which ever is greater?

Comment: Sure, so with the method I stated above you can get the amount of positive and negative words. Once done you can compare both and see which is greater. eg if(badWords > goodWords) { // More bad words } else { // More good words }

Comment: Hmm...I have never worked with array's, That is a bit more advanced than where I am currently at I think.

Comment: Arrays aren't that complicated, for your needs you would need something like this:
// set up and initialize
String[] badWordsHolder = new String[i]; // i would be the number of bad words

// Define the words
badWordsHolder[0] = "BadWord1";
badWordsHolder[1] = "BadWord2";
// and so on

Then you can iterate through the array like so:
for(int iteration = 0; iteration < badWordsHolder.length; iteration++) {
if(badWordsHolder[iteration] == currentWordInText) {
// The word is a bad word
}
}

Comment: Sorry, I kept on pressing enter. :P

Comment: Thats ok. Thanks for that.So I understand the array now at a basic level. But how do I get the program to search th coversation.txt file based on an array?

Comment: You would iterate through every word in the conversation.txt and compare it with the words in the array. I suggest you read up abou the array here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Thanks Luke. I will give it a go and see if I can get something to work.

Comment: So I have tried to get this working using an array. As I said I understand how to set an array up but now I do not understand how to get it to iterate through the ConversationTest.txt file using the array I set up and do the count. This is what I have so far:

Comment: I was not sure how to get the code posted and it posted as an answer to my own question. When in fact it is not an answer but another question. : )

Comment: I now have it working where it will iterate through the ConversationTest.txt file based on the array of "good words" I have set up. I now can't figure out how to get it to count them and give me a total. Code I have now is in the answer section as I don't know where I should be putting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
package omgilisearch;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SentimentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          printAllCounts(
            readWordFile("ConversationTest.txt"));
        }

private static Map<String, Integer> readWordFile(String string) {

        return null;
    }

String[] goodWordsHolder = new String[3];{

goodWordsHolder[0] = "good"; goodWordsHolder[1] = "great";goodWordsHolder[2] = "excellent";

for(int iteration = 0; iteration < goodWordsHolder.length; iteration++) { String currentWordInText;
if(goodWordsHolder[iteration] == currentWordInText) { }// The word is a bad word } }

private static void printAllCounts(Map<String, Integer> frequencyData) {
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
          System.out.println(" Occurrences Word");
          for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : frequencyData.entrySet())
            System.out.printf("%15d %s\n", e.getValue(), e.getKey());
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        }
}
```

Comment: This may seem like a silly question but....Why do I need to use an array? Surely with my original code where it gives me a count per word found there is a way to add a variable (integer?) that gives a "Total count"?

Answer (score 0):

```
package omgilisearch;

import java.io.*;

   public class SentimentTest {     

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] lines = new String[0];         
    String path = "ConversationTest.txt";         
    BufferedReader br = null;      
    try {

             File file = new File(path);

        br = new BufferedReader(                  
             new InputStreamReader(                  
             new FileInputStream(file)));             

    String line;             
    while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {                 

    lines = add(line, lines);

             }             

    br.close(); 

      } catch(IOException e) {             

    System.out.println("read error: " + e.getMessage());

         }         
    print(lines);     

    }       

    private static String[] add(String s, String[] array) { 

        String[] goodWordsHolder = new String[3];{

        }goodWordsHolder[0] = "good"; goodWordsHolder[1] = "great";goodWordsHolder[2] = "excellent";
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < goodWordsHolder.length; iteration++) { String currentWordInText = null; if(goodWordsHolder[iteration] == currentWordInText) { }}
        return goodWordsHolder; } 

    private static void print(String[] data) {

       for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)             
    System.out.println(data[i]);     
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays store multiple items of the same information type eg. String[] badWords;. I believe you should use this, since I'm sure you will have more than 1 bad word that you would like to find in the conversation text, if not, then simple use 1 String eg. String badWord;.

I'm not going to write out all the code that will make it work, I'll just give you an algorithm.

```
public class test {

// The process of picking out all the good and bad words
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Setting up all the needed variables
        // Set up all the good words
        String[] goodWordsHolder = new String[2];
        goodWordsHolder[0] = "firstGoodWord";
        goodWordsHolder[1] = "secondGoodWord";
        // Set up all the bad words
        String[] badWordsHolder = new String[2];
        badWordsHolder[0] = "firstBadWord";
        badWordsHolder[1] = "secondBadWord";
        // Set up the counters
        int amountOfGoodWords = 0;
        int amountOfBadWords = 0;
        int currentWordInText = 0;
        // boolean that will exit the loop
        boolean ConversationEnded = false;

    while(!ConversationEnded) {
        // Compare the currentWord from the conversation with the hard coded words
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < goodWordsHolder.length; iteration++) { 
            if(goodWordsHolder[iteration] == getWordInText(currentWordInText)) {
                amountOfGoodWords++;
            }   
        }
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < badWordsHolder.length; iteration++) { 
            if(badWordsHolder[iteration] == getWordInText(currentWordInText)) {
                amountOfBadWords++;
            }   
        }
        // Increase the current word value so the next time we compare the next word in the conversation will be compared
        currentWordInText++;

        // Check that we haven't reached the end of the conversation
        if(endOfTheConversationHasBeenReached()) {
            // This will exit the while loop
            ConversationEnded = true;
        }
    }

    // Now print all the information to the console
    System.out.println("Amount of good Words: " + amountOfGoodWords);
    System.out.println("Amount of bad Words: " + amountOfBadWords);
    if(amountOfGoodWords > amountOfBadWords) {
        System.out.println("There are more good words than bad words.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("There are more bad words than good words.");
    }

}


// The method(s) you'll have to code out yourself. I suggest you read up on the web and so on to assist you with this.

private static String getWordInText(int currentWordInText) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private static boolean endOfTheConversationHasBeenReached() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

Excuse me if there are any logical errors. The code hasn't been debugged yet. ;) Hopefully this will guide you into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I will have a go at using this as a templarte of sorts.